# Compute Youden index from two density plot

Tags: r, threshold, density-plot

I need help with calculating the Youden index in a two density plot in R. Basically, I need to calculate the value where two density plots are overlapping 
The variables are numeric.

Is there any method for calculating this value (Youden index) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could expand [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25454464/6574038) to get the coordinates (i.e. the `y`, too) for the intersection *point*.

Accordingly, first the two distributions are to be combined and indexed and the minimum and maximum calculated to make them comparable.

Second, use `density` to compute the kernel density estimates for each distribution.

The coordinates we can get with `which(diff((d2$y - d1$y) > 0) != 0) + 1` for `x` and `y` as shown below.

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1e3
dat <- data.frame(v=c(rnorm(n, 1, 3), rnorm(n, 5, 3)),
                  grp=rep(1:2, each=n))

lo <- min(dat$v)
up <- max(dat$v)

d1 <- density(dat$v[dat$grp == 1], from=lo, to=up, n=2^10)
d2 <- density(dat$v[dat$grp == 2], from=lo, to=up, n=2^10)

intersection.point <- cbind(x=d1$x[which(diff((d2$y - d1$y) > 0) != 0) + 1], 
                            y=d1$y[which(diff((d2$y - d1$y) > 0) != 0) + 1])
```

***Plot***

```
plot(d1, ylim=c(0, .14), main="Intersection point")
lines(d2)
points(intersection.point, col="red", pch=19)
legend("topright", pch=19, col="red", legend="intersection point")
```

[image]